# mysql with jdbc returning fully qualified column names

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jooq

I have a java web application and mysql 5.7 as database, and using jooq 3.8.2 to execute JDBC code.

Executing the following select:

```
Result<Record> result = dsl.select(TABLE1.fields())
                           .select(TABLE2.fields())
                           .from(TABLE1)
                           .join(TABLE2).ON(TABLE1.FK.eq(TABLE2.ID))
                           .fetch();
for(Record rec : result) {
   Table1Record tb1Rec = rec.into(TABLE1);
   Table2Record tb2Rec = rec.into(TABLE2);
}
```

After updating jooq to version 3.8.2, my logs shows the following message:

```
INFO  org.jooq.impl.Fields - Ambiguous match found for ....
```

To me, it's clear that the problem is that both tables have some columns with same names. So I tried (as example):

```
Field tb1Field = TABLE1.FIELD1;
dsl.select(tb1Field.as("TABLE1_" + tb1Field.getName())
```

But then

```
Table1Record tb1Rec = rec.get(TABLE1);
```

returns null.

My preferred solution is, in same way, force mysql return fully qualified column names, but I can't found any option to do that.

Any help?

Comment: Hmm, that message shouldn't appear. There is no ambiguity in the query you've shown, at least when you use generated code for `TABLE1` etc. Can you show the DDL for your two `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` tables? (i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statement)?

Comment: My tables has so many columns, but just as example, if I have TABLE1.ID and TABLE2.ID in the select, the problem arises.

The result in mysql console will be:

      -------------
      | ID  |  ID |
      -------------
      (any value)

Comment: If mysql prefixes the table names in result, the problem not arises. But I didn't find any configuration to do this, either in mysql or in JDBC.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I cannot really seem to be able to reproduce this issue. Only thing you could try is upgrading to 3.8.4, but [I don't think anything in this area was fixed...](http://www.jooq.org/notes/?version=3.8)